# Loan and Annuity problem - finding X

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I am new in finance math, and I am working on this problem. I was wondering if someone could help me solve it.

A loan of $10,000$ is to be repaid with annual payments, at the end of
each year, for the next $21$ years. For the first $7$ years the payments
are $X$ per year, the second $7$ years they are $2X$ per year, and for the
third $7$ years they are $3X$ per year.

a) Find $X$ if $i^{(2)} =10% $

b) Find $X$ if $i^{(2)} = 8%$ for the first 10 years and $i^{(2)} = 12%$ afterwards.

---

My attempt was

a) My timeline looked like $7$ Xs starting from $t=1$ to $7$, then $2X$ from $8$ to $14$ and then $3X$ from $15$ to $21$.

$$PV = 10000 $$

$$PV = X a_{\overline{7} \rceil.05} + (1.05)^{-7} *2X a_{\overline{14} \rceil.05} + (1.05)^{-14} * 3X a_{\overline{21} \rceil.05} $$

$$10000 = \frac{X[1-(1.05)^{-7}]}{\frac{0.05}{1.05}} + (1.05)^{-7}\frac{2X[1-(1.05)^{-14}]}{\frac{0.05}{1.05}} + (1.05)^{-14}\frac{3X[1-(1.05)^{-21}]}{\frac{0.05}{1.05}}  $$

When I calculate it I got $243.70$

I wasn't sure if $(1.05)^{-7}$ for example was needed since I am starting at year 8 and bring it to time 0 , where the present value of 2X is 7 payments. Same for $(1.05)^{-14}$

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearest way to proceed is to first calculate the effective periodic rate--in this case, the rate is annual.  Since you are given a nominal rate of interest $i^{(2)}$, we must convert this to the effective annual rate $i$ via the formula $$\left(1 + \frac{i^{(m)}}{m}\right)^m = 1 + i.$$
In the first question, the interest rate is constant throughout the repayment term, which is simpler; we have $$i = \left(1 + \frac{0.10}{2}\right)^2 - 1 = 0.1025.$$  Then our equation of value is $$\require{enclose} 10000 = X a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i} + 2X v^7 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i} + 3X v^{14} a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i}. \tag{1}$$  This can also be written
$$10000 = X a_{\enclose{actuarial}{21}i} + X v^7 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{14}i} + X v^{14} a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i}. \tag{2}$$
Your equation is not correct because it is computing the present value of cash flow in which the first $7$ payments are $X$, the next $7$ payments are $2X$, the next $7$ payments are $5X$, and then another $14$ payments are $3X$.  This is because the term of the second deferred annuity is $14$ years, so you are paying at times $t = 8, 9, \ldots 21$ the amount $2X$, and then starting from $t = 15$, you are paying another $3X$ from the third annuity.

To avoid this confusion, it is helpful to write out the cash flow:
$$PV = (Xv + Xv^2 + \cdots + Xv^7) + (2Xv^8 + 2Xv^9 + \cdots + 2Xv^{14}) + (3Xv^{15} + 3Xv^{16} + \cdots 3Xv^{21}).$$  And now if you factor things out, we get $$PV = X(v + v^2 + \cdots + v^7) + 2Xv^7(v + v^2 + \cdots + v^7) + 3Xv^{14}(v + v^2 + \cdots + v^7).$$  And we can factor this even further to get $$PV = X(1 + 2v^7 + 3v^{14})a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i}. \tag{3}$$  We can also factor Equation $(1)$ in the same way.

So where does Equation $(2)$ come from?  Well, we could have written the cash flow instead as
$$PV = X(v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{21}) + X(v^8 + v^9 + \cdots + v^{21}) + X(v^{15} + v^{16} + \cdots + v^{21}).$$  You can see that the first annuity of $X$ has a $21$-year term, and the second has a $14$-year term deferred by $7$ years, so that these contributions of $X$ will contribute the proper amount to the final $7$ years of the overall repayment.

How do we do the second part?  In this case, we must calculate two effective rates of interest.  One approach is to calculate the effective annual rate for the first $10$-year period, call that $i = (1 + 0.08/2)^2 - 1 = 0.0816$, and then the effective annual rate for the remainder of the term, call that $j = (1 + 0.12/2)^2 - 1 = 0.1236$.  Then the equation of value becomes
$$10000 = Xa_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i} + 2Xv_i^7 (a_{\enclose{actuarial}{3}i} + v_i^3 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{4}j}) + 3Xv_i^{10} v_j^4 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}j}, \tag{4}$$  where $v_i = 1/(1+i)$ and $v_j = 1/(1+j)$ are the effective annual present value discount factors for each interest period.  Note we must split up the second $7$-year payment period into two deferred annuities due to the change in interest rate after time $t = 10$.  Also note that the total present value discount factor of the last $7$ payments is neither $v_i^{14}$ nor $v_j^{14}$ but rather $v_i^{10} v_j^4$ because for the first $10$ years of deferral, we are under rate $i$, and for the next $4$ years of deferral, we are under rate $j$.

This leads us to ask whether there is an analogue of Equation $(2)$ for this question.  The answer is yes, and as usual, to understand how to get it, we write out the cash flow:
$$\begin{align}
PV &= X(v_i + v_i^2 + \cdots v_i^7) + 2X(v_i^8 + v_i^9 + v_i^{10} + v_i^{10}v_j + v_i^{10}v_j^2 + v_i^{10}v_j^3 + v_i^{10}v_j^4) \\
&\quad + 3X(v_i^{10}v_j^5 + \cdots v_i^{10}v_j^{11}) \\
&= X(v_i + v_i^2 + \cdots v_i^{10} + v_i^{10}v_j + \cdots + v_i^{10}v_j^{11}) \\
&\quad + X(v_i^8 + v_i^9 + v_i^{10} + v_i^{10}v_j + \cdots v_i^{10}v_j^{11}) \\
&\quad + X(v_i^{10}v_j^5 + \cdots v_i^{10}v_j^{11}). \end{align} \tag{5}$$
This gives the equation of value
$$\begin{align}10000 &= X(a_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i} + v_i^{10} a_{\enclose{actuarial}{11}j}) + X(v_i^7 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{3}i} + v_i^{10} a_{\enclose{actuarial}{11}j}) + X v_i^{10} v_j^4 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}j}.\end{align}\tag{6} $$

Comment: Hi for eq (1) and (2) what is put for i for v^7 for example, is it (1+0.1025)^-7 or (1+0.05)^-7 ?

Comment: @comp890 In Equations (1) and (2), $v = 1/(1+i) = 1/(1+0.1025)$.

Comment: I am so confused about what formulas to use. how come the formula I put above doesn't work?

Comment: I am getting two different answers from eq (1) and (2) 676.81 and 464.31 respectively but they are supposed to be the same

Comment: @comp890 Neither one is correct.  You should get $X = 746.1911165$.  Note $$\require{enclose} a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i} = \frac{1 - v^7}{i} = \frac{1 - (1.1025)^{-7}}{0.1025} \approx 4.82861, \\ a_{\enclose{actuarial}{14}i} = \frac{1 - v^{14}}{i} = \frac{1 - (1.1025)^{-14}}{0.1025} \approx 7.26738, \\ a_{\enclose{actuarial}{21}i} = \frac{1 - v^{21}}{i} = \frac{1 - (1.1025)^{-21}}{0.1025} \approx 8.49913.$$

Comment: I see, I'll try again. I'm wondering why I put i/1+i for the denominator shown above.

Comment: Thank you I got it now!

Comment: btw for (5) how did you isolate the 2 and 3 from X?

Comment: @comp890 It is the same idea as in Equations (1) and (2).  The series of payments can be reimagined as $21$ payments of $X$ at times $t = 1, 2, \ldots, 21$, plus $14$ payments of $X$ at times $8, 9, \ldots, 21$, plus $7$ payments of $X$ at times $15, 16, \ldots, 21$.  Now calculate the total present value discounting for each of these.  So for example, at time $t = 12$, there has been $10$ years of discounting at rate $i$, and $2$ years of discounting at rate $j$, so the present value discount factor is $v_i^{10} v_j^2$.

Comment: Yes, I see it now! thank you so much for explaining. The algebra part is bit long but it makes so much sense to include it to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{enclose}$
$\def \annuity #1{a_{\enclose{actuarial}{#1}}}$
The formula should be

$$PV = X \annuity7 + (1.05)^{-7} *2X \annuity7 + (1.05)^{-14} * 3X \annuity7$$

In each case you have $7$ years of payments. For example, $$2X\annuity7$$ is the present value of the $7$ payments of $2X$ as of the end of the seventh year.  We then multiply by $(1.05)^{-7}$ to bring it back to the date of the loan, so that we compute all present values as of the same date.

Notice the way that I was able to get better-looking annuity symbols.  I got the idea from [here](https://www.acted.co.uk/forums/index.php?threads/typesetting-mathematics-on-these-forums-with-mathjax.8067/).  Look a the first two lines of my answer in the editor.  The first line says we need the "enclose" library.  The second line defines an \annuity macro which we can use line a pre-defined macro such as \sqrt.

The linked source also shows an example of a much more complicated life annuity.  You probably haven't gotten up to this yet.

**EDIT**

I made a mistake earlier, in that I forgot that then interest rate is $5\%$ every $6$ months.  The formula should actually be
$$PV = X \annuity7 + (1.05)^{-14} *2X \annuity7 + (1.05)^{-28} * 3X \annuity7$$ because there are two compounding periods a year.  Since the payments are made annually, the annuities are computed at the equivalent annual rate, namely $$i=(1.05)^2-1=10.25\%$$

As to your comment, you've made the same mistake with the exponents, but otherwise I think you've got it right.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Just wanted to make sure, For b) it says for the first 10 years with 8%, and then rest is 12%  so that means the timeline is split for two different interest i. So for the first 10 years, we will have 7 payments for X plus the first 3 payments of 2X times by the (1.04)^-7, then we add this with the rest of the years with 4 payments of 2X * (1.06)^-10 plus the 7 payments of 3X * (1.06)^-14?

Comment: @saulspats I am having trouble understanding the exponents. I thought for the 7 payments of 2X you start exactly where the first 2X is and move backwards to 0 to get the exponent -7 and not -14.

Comment: it said annually not semiannually (6 months)

Comment: $i^{(n)}$ means a nominal annual rate, compounded $n$ times a year.  If the bank says that the interest rate on a loan is $6\%$ annually, they mean it's half a percent a month, which is $1.005^{12}-1\approx6.16778\%$ annually.